# calculate probability for two draws in a row, with the first round indicating chances

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

In order to win a game, Alice has to do two actions:

a) draw a number. She can draw any number from 1 to 100, each number having the same probability to be drawn. This first draw indicates her success chances. Let's call this number X.

b) she draws another number, the same from 1 to 100 with each number having the same probability to be drawn. Let's call this number Y.

In order to win, X must be greater or equal to Y.

How do I calculate her probability to win overall? First time she draws her probability level then she draws a number that must be less or equal to the first number. So, if she draws for X number 2, her probability is really really low to win, But if she draws for X number 98, her probability is really high.

How do I calculate the chances overall?

Comment: Imagine a $100\times100$ matrix, where each spot in the matrix represents one of the (equally likely) $10,000$ possibilities for the two draws. For how many of the matrix locations does Alice win?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Alice draws the same number twice, she wins.  What is the chance of that?  What is the chance she draws two different numbers?  Given that she draws two different numbers, she wins half the time, because one order wins and one loses.  Add the full chance of matching draws and half the chance of different draws to get the total winning probability.

Comment: As stated in the initial description each number has the same probability to be drawn. Since there are 100 numbers, this means each number has a probability of 1%. Probability is equal for all numbers in the pool.

Comment: @skydanc3r:  that is correct.  Now you should be able to finish what I suggested.

Comment: Considering first number X and second Y, there are 5050 combinations of X and Y that win. There are 5049 combinations of X and Y that lose, so 5050 / (5049 + 5050) = 0.5000495098524606 or ~50.00495% - this sounds correct?

Comment: You are close, but your losing count is not correct.  How many total XY pairs are there?  You have counted the winning ones, so the losing ones are ??

Comment: You are right because of the equal condition (X=1,Y=1 win and X=100,Y=100 win). the losing ones are 4950, so a total of 10000 possible cases out of which 5050 wins, probability is 0.505 or 50.5%?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Think of this in a more simpler way, where you can only draw 1's and 2's.

Therefore, there can be 4 combinations.

$X=1, Y=1$

$X=1, Y=2$

$X=2, Y=1$

$X=2, Y=2$

In cases 1, 3, and 4, the player wins, so there is a 75% chance of winning.

Let's try it when you can only get 1's, 2's and 3's.

$X=1, Y=1$

$X=1, Y=2$

$X=1, Y=3$

$X=2, Y=1$

$X=2, Y=2$

$X=2, Y=3$

$X=3, Y=1$

$X=3, Y=2$

$X=3, Y=3$

The chances of winning here are 6/9 or $66.\overline6$ percent.

Try this when you get 1's, 2's 3's, and 4's.

$X=1, Y=1$

$X=1, Y=2$

$X=1, Y=3$

$X=1, Y=4$

$X=2, Y=1$

$X=2, Y=2$

$X=2, Y=3$

$X=2, Y=4$

$X=3, Y=1$

$X=3, Y=2$

$X=3, Y=3$

$X=3, Y=4$

$X=4, Y=1$

$X=4, Y=2$

$X=4, Y=3$

$X=4, Y=4$

Therefore, there is a 10/16 or $62.5$% chance of winning.

Do you notice the relationship we get?

Comment: You mean 0.625 chance of winning or 62.5%.

Comment: @stretch Sorry about that, I'll fix it.

Comment: Spoiler: If you draw a 1 during the first time, there is a 100% chance of winning. If you draw a 2 during the first time, there is a 99% chance of winning. If you draw a 100 during the first time, there is a 1% chance of winning. This can be described as
$$\frac{100+99+98+97+....+1}{99+98+97+...+1}$$
since $X$ can be equal to $Y$ and the player can win.

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret this. This results to 1.000198 - what is the probability percent here?

Comment: also, the logic on the first equation is good but it's hard to extend it to while x = {1,100} and y = 1{1,100} manually it takes a lot of time. Thought there's something straight forward.

Comment: This equation above is self-explanatory and straightforward, and also quite easy to calculate.